# How to dynamically subtract one column from another and output a new value based on the previous row in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power Bi table where there are four columns that matter: Sales Order, Material, Quantity Sum, and Unrestricted Total. Sales order - material pairs are unique in the table.

What I am trying to do is calculate the remaining stock after the "Quantity Sum" is subtracted from the stock. The stock table I appended using the merge operation and it appended stock value to each of the entry with certain material #. As you can see, we have 1 PCs available in stock for material 10732 but it appends it 4 times even though we have only 1 in stock. Perhaps I could connect/merge the tables differently to avoid this. I will attach a screenshot of the table.
For example:

```
Sales Order; Material; Quantity Sum; Unrestricted Total; Desired Output;
  38851164;   10732;     2;            1;                    1
  38511240;   10732;     2;            1;                    3
  38792557;   10732;     2;            1;                    5
  38879079;   10732;     2;            1;                    7
  38851164;   10820;     8;            0;                    8;
  38511240;   10820;     8;            0;                    16;
  38879079;   10820;     8;            0;                    24;
```

Note: Desired output could be both negative or positive, it doesn't matter.
I have tried using "Earlier" DAX function but it didn't really provide the desired output. I used the following expression

```
Total Required =
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Qty],
    FILTER (
        zppgfm_mat_req,
        EARLIER ( zppgfm_mat_req[Material] ) >= zppgfm_mat_req[Material]
    )
)
```

and

```
Sum Qty =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( zppgfm_mat_req[Unrestricted Total] )
        - SUM ( zppgfm_mat_req[Quantity Sum] )
)
```

Please advise on how could I approach this? I would appreciate any assistance. Perhaps, I could try merging the stock table with material requirements differently to not get duplicated stock values? My original Stock table has material# and Unrestricted Total stock with the "Entry date" value for when the stock was updated.
Sample Stock table:

```
Material;Stock Added; Unrestricted Total;
10723; 11/08/2022; 1;
10820; 11/08/2022; 0;
10928; 11/08/2022; 117;
```

This is the output of the measure that I have tried.
[image: Measure that I tried]